# What all do I need to salvage parts from gaming devices (not for profit)

Tags: components

I have a few projects I want to get started on (not for patent: only for me) I wanted to know what types of tools I need to get some components and other salvageable parts from things like a PS2 controller, or other console related devices. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Ask a question appropriate for a Stackexchange site and you might get a useful answer.

Answer (score 2):

In general, a small soldering iron and some wick will allow you to disassemble most anything.

However, also in general, modern electronics contain so many surface-mounted, custom, and poorly-labeled parts that they are not useful anywhere else. Modern manufacturing is geared towards rapid assembly, not disassembly or repair. You won't get a BGA package off the board without some $pecial tools, and it's unlikely you can use it later.

Given the cost of components these days, unless you want the primary CPU it's just not worth your time. And if the CPU is direct-mounted (no socket) then it's not worth your time either. If you limit your parts harvesting to through-hole and large-foot surface-mount (like we had in the analog era) then it's easy.

Comment: BGA packages actually can be removed and re-balled with rudimentary equipment.

Answer (score 2):

You can heat the back of the board with a propane torch or paint stripper heat gun and whack it to knock the parts off just as soon the solder liquifies, then clean them up with solder wick.

Terrible environmentally (and for personal safety) as the temperatures will break down a lot of materials and can cause them to emit hazardous gases. If the solder is lead based, could contaminate the area if you allow the temperatures to get too high, and could damage parts if you're not fast about it.

It is fast, though. And probably illegal as well as undesirable in most developed countries.